# Split a dynamic string as levels

Tags: sql, string, split

I have table containing dynamics string that changes in length as per the example below

```
string 1: A.B.C:D.E.F:G.H.I:J
 string 2: A.B.C:D
```

I need to split the string to get to the following design :

```
level_0
     level_1
        level_2
          level_N
             level_Attribute
```

so for example for String 2 the design will be

```
level_0: A
     level_1: B
        level_2: C
             level_Attribute: D
```

I was able to split and create the colunm and assign each value to a level using the following

```
DECLARE  @str VARCHAR(100)='A.B.C:D.E.F:G.H.I:J';
set @str=REPLACE(@str,':','.')
DECLARE @JsonArray NVARCHAR(MAX)=CONCAT('[["',REPLACE(@str,'.','","'),'"]]');

SELECT @str                          AS TheOriginal
      ,@JsonArray                    AS TransformedToJSON
      ,ValuesFromTheArray.*
FROM OPENJSON(@JsonArray)
WITH(Level_0  VARCHAR(100) '$[0]'
    ,Level_1 VARCHAR(100) '$[1]'
    ,Level_2 VARCHAR(100) '$[2]'
    ,Level_3 VARCHAR(100) '$[3]'
    ,Level_4 VARCHAR(100) '$[4]'
    ,Level_5 VARCHAR(100) '$[5]'
    ,Level_6 VARCHAR(100) '$[6]'
    ,Level_7 VARCHAR(100) '$[7]'
    ,Level_8 VARCHAR(100) '$[8]'
    ,Level_Attribute VARCHAR(100) '$[9]'

    ) ValuesFromTheArray
```

My problem is when the string is short , the last item is not added to the level_attribute.

Comment: I do not get your notation.  A.B.C:D.E.F:G.H.I:J  should this be 'A.B.C.D.E.F.G.H.I:J'.  Nine levels and one attribute?

Comment: this is how my data comes as A.B.C:D.E.F:G.H.I:J, I do a replace to change ':' to '.' and yes Nine levels and one attribute but my data is not always 9 levels so what I need to accomplish is whatever how many levels I have the last one must be saved as an attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem.  I am choosing to leave the level as one big string and the attribute as another string.  Lets create the table and insert data.

```
-- 1 - create table
create table sample_levels
(
sample_data varchar(128)
);

-- 2 - add data
insert into sample_levels values ('A.B.C:D.E.F:G.H.I:J');
insert into sample_levels values ('A.B.C:D');
```

The trick is to convert to comma delimited string and reverse and parse.

```
-- get level + attribute
select 
  substring(backwards, 1, charindex(',', backwards) - 1) as attribute,
  reverse(substring(backwards, charindex(',', backwards) + 1, len(backwards) - charindex(',', backwards) )) as levels
from
(
  select 
  reverse(replace(replace(sample_data, '.', ','), ':', ',')) as backwards
  from sample_levels
) as d
```

I did this example in SQL Fiddle.  Here is the link to play with the SQL code.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d16f4/1/0

[image]

Comment: The next question is the following.  Does level needs to be split into 9 different columns. Before SQL Server 2016, one had to write their own string split.  What database engine are you using??

Comment: Thank you for your answer it works fine and yes the levels needs to be splitted but not always into 9 columns it will depends on the data, I am using SMSS